# AWS local build (CodeBuild) pass credentials file with wsl2

Tags: docker, windows-10, aws-codebuild, wsl-2

I upgraded my docker desktop to the version 3.2.1 (61626), and choose to use wsl2, after that i cannot run Local builds of AWS CodeBuild because the AWS configuration is not being found, the command I use is (I run the command from a tab from Windows terminal using ubuntu 20 that I installed from the store):

```
./codebuild_build.sh -i aws/codebuild/standard:5.0 -a ./ -s ./  -b ./buildspec.yml  -c ~/.aws
```

That command works with the version of docker that uses Hyper-V, after the upgrade to wsl2 i get the error:

```
agent_1  | [Container] 2021/03/05 21:04:05 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
agent_1  | [Container] 2021/03/05 21:04:05 Phase context status code: Decrypted Variables Error Message: MissingRegion: could not find region configuration
```

The docker command that is generated is the following:

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e "IMAGE_NAME=aws/codebuild/standard:5.0" -e "ARTIFACTS=/mnt/c/[redacted]" -e "SOURCE=/mnt/c/[redacted]" -e "BUILDSPEC=/mnt/c/[redacted]" -e "AWS_CONFIGURATION=NONE" -e "INITIATOR=[redacted]" amazon/aws-codebuild-local:latest
```

edit:
running the command from git bash the generated command is:

```
winpty docker run -it -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e "IMAGE_NAME=aws/codebuild/standard:5.0" -e "ARTIFACTS=//C/[redacted]" -e "SOURCE=//C/[redacted]" -e "BUILDSPEC=//C/[redacted]" -e "AWS_CONFIGURATION=//C/Users/[redacted]/.aws" -e "INITIATOR=[redacted]" amazon/aws-codebuild-local:latest
```

But also fails with the error:

```
agent_1  | [Container] 2021/03/05 22:17:43 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
agent_1  | [Container] 2021/03/05 22:17:43 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: stat /codebuild/output/srcDownload/src/buildspec.pr.yml: no such file or directory
```

With the previous command the variable AWS_CONFIGURATION had the path to my .aws folder, I had tried -c //c/Users/[myProfile]/.aws and /mnt/c/Users/[myProfile]/.aws but AWS_CONFIGURATION is always NONE

Is there a configuration that I'm missing? or I need add an extra step with wsl2?

Edit:
I installed Ubuntu 18 and failed in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.  I realized that since I had to run docker as root using the `sudo` command, my home directory was now `/root` instead of `/home/<username>`.

There may be a better way around this, but I symlinked the folder `/home/<username>/.aws` to `/root/.aws`.

Also, you could pass the variables AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID in through an environment file using the `-e` flag of the `codebuild_build.sh`command.